# Qt Creator custom build step cannot copy file

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I wanna to copy a file to build dist directory in Qt Creator Custom Build Step:

[image]
But after I Build, the error thrown:

```
 Could not start process "copy" C:\Users\W\Desktop\StockKLine-master\StockKLine-master\dataKLine.txt C:\Users\W\Desktop\StockKLine-master\build-StockKLine-Desktop_Qt_5_11_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\dataKLine.txt /Y
```

[image]

However I can test the command in the cmd.exe without error

[image]

How Can I copy a file to dist folder in Qt Creator Custom Build Step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**copy** is internal command for **cmd**. (See for example [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html))

You should use **cmd** to execute shell that will do the work and exit immediate (/c option), so it should looks something like:

Command: `cmd`

Arguments: `/c copy %{sourceDir}\dataKLine.txt %{buildDir}\dataKLine.txt /Y`

Other possibility will be to use **xcopy**:

Command: `xcopy`

Arguments: `%{sourceDir}\dataKLine.txt %{buildDir}\dataKLine.txt /Y /I`