# Qt Creator custom build step : generic cross-platform way to copy files/directories

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I need to add a custom build step which copies files.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903663/qt-creator-custom-build-step-cannot-copy-file) has a Windows-specific answer to this problem, I need a cross-platform
one.

I already tried using  `$(COPY_DIR)` but it is not understood as the generic copy command as it is in Qmake like in [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083441/how-to-add-pre-build-step-in-qmake-qtcreator).

Comment: Does it have to be in Qt Creator's build steps? Could you add it to your qmake file instead?

Comment: I did so, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Or at least, only sometimes...

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438513/7427152

Comment: @JarMan Yes, I did exactly that before going for the custom build step. That's the attempt I describe in the second part of my question.

Comment: I use that example in my projects too, but haven’t seen a problem. Are you getting an error of some kind?